# How to add counter columns to get the frequency of items in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, counter

i have such dataframe:

| product1 | product2 | product3 | product4 | product5 | product6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| straws | orange | melon | chair | bread | milk |
| melon | milk | book | coffee | cake | tea |
| bread | bananas | juice | chair | book | straws |

I wish to add 6 counting items columns along the index and counts per rows the number of times they appear in the dataframe.

| CountProduct1 | CountProduct2 | CountProduct3 | Countproduct4 | Countproduct5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you describe the expected output?

Comment: why would 'bread' in the 3rd row have a count of 1 and not 2 (it appears before in row 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the modified explanation, here is a way to do it.

**1. cumulative counts**

```py
cnt = df.apply(lambda g: g.value_counts(), axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int).cumsum()
>>> cnt
   bananas  book  bread  cake  chair  coffee  juice  melon  milk  orange  straws  tea
0  0        0     1      0     1      0       0      1      1     1       1       0  
1  0        1     1      1     1      1       0      2      2     1       1       1  
2  1        2     2      1     2      1       1      2      2     1       2       1
```

**2. replace each item by the corresponding count, row by row**

```py
out = pd.DataFrame([
    r.map(c) for (_, r), (_, c) in zip(df.T.items(), cnt.T.items())
]).set_axis([f'Count{k}' for k in df.columns], axis=1)

>>> out
   Countproduct1  Countproduct2  Countproduct3  Countproduct4  Countproduct5  Countproduct6
0  1              1              1              1              1              1            
1  2              2              1              1              1              1            
2  2              1              1              2              2              2
```

Comment: not really in fact. it's more like  rolling count columns like countproduct1, countproduct2,countproduct3, countproduct4, countproduct5, countproduct6. Straws appear in first row so it count 1, then appear in the thrid row but in product 6 so count 2 in columns 'countproduct6'.

Comment: I just edit the columns for more clearance.

Comment: it works. Thanks a lot man. I would never get by without you.